# Convert PowerPoint slides to MP4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powerpoint, wait

```
objPres.SaveAs(filename2, Powerpoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsMP4);
```

I am trying to open a PowerPoint Presentation and do a save as in MP4 format. Since some time delay is needed for this conversion, when I run the program I get no output. But once I add a breakpoint on the above line and then proceed step by step I get an MP4 video as output.

Please help me out. How to make the program wait until the conversion is over? I have tried the code below also but it is not working:

```
while (!File.Exists(filename2))
{
    objPres.SaveAs(filename2, Powerpoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsMP4);
}
```

Comment: Maybe **[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670072/waiting-for-something-to-happen-asynchronous-or-synchronous-model)** could help.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The thing is instead of just giving 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
Is there any other way to check if the MP4 is ready or the conversion is over. That will be more logical since the size of PPT is unpredictable

Comment: **I know** this is a bad practice actually but have you tried doing the operation before that `while` and do nothing in the loop since it's only meant to keep program running further until the file created? And there is a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) class. I dont really know how it works but you may wanna check it out.

Comment: Thanks... The problem is File.Exists will return true from the very beginning itself but the size will be zero. I will try whether I can include size as one of the condition.
Also I will try for some power point functions itself to obtain that progress bar which is shown in Power Point 2013 while converting a presentation to MP4. If it worked will let you know !